# firebase "firebase deploy --only functions" error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to run

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

command but it gives me many error what can i do?

[image: image of error]

Comment: I'd recommend posting the contents of the `functions/index.js` file noted in that ESLint error because there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post images of text here, see [the discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Appears the eslint script (in package.json) is erroring. Is the package installing correctly and if so next simply see that it runs properly by running it in the functions directory. If there's an error it would indicate a possible solution/problem. Be sure to use v14 (and not v15) to deploy as well--at least currently that results in ambiguous errors.

Comment: @jimmont I think that this answer is reasonable for me. Can you move this to an answer?

Comment: quite remarkable the downvotes--what a place SO has become... answer added @gisshizuku45

Answer (score 2):

reading through the error info shared it looks like the deployment is trying to run one of the package.json scripts for eslint and failing, to quickly see if that's the case simply disable that based on what's in the package.json

if you want the linting to happen just finish setting it up, otherwise remove the related dependencies and configuration, linting can be useful, however it can also become quite onerous without auto-fixing (I can't remember that unrelated detail at the moment... possibly `--fix`) so it's a good thing to work out along with whatever automation relates to the work and team